# the maximum no of email send objects that I can retrieve using API

Tags: marketing-cloud, limits

What is the maximum number of email send objects that I can retrieve using the Exact target API per one API call?

Comment: Could it be sensefull to scope your question, per api call, per day, per something else ?

Comment: Did the answer below help you out?

Answer (score 1):

Each API call is limited to 2500 records. You can however use the `ContinueRequest` property to retrieve the rest of the results.

Essentially - you will get back the retrieve request's `OverallStatus`, which provides the following responses:

- OK - Status code stating that all objects were successfully retrieved.
- Error - Status code stating that an error occurred during the retrieve option. The first step in resolving this error is to verify the value of the Properties property.
- MoreDataAvailable - Status code indicating that more data is available for RetrieveRequest. A RetrieveRequest returning more than 2500 records will have this status.

If the `OverallStatus` is `MoreDataAvailable`, pass the request objectID into a new retrieve request and it will get the remaining items.